# Catching inactive state of watchOS2

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos-2

In my iOS `AppDelegate`, there is a method called `applicationWillResignActive`, which notifies the app that it is about to transition to the inactive state.

Is there something similar to this in watchOS 2?

How could I know when my Apple Watch will transition to inactive state and then return from being inactive? I need to count how much time it is inactive.

Answer (score 0):

watchOS 2 has `applicationDidBecomeActive()` and `applicationWillResignActive()`.

This is documented in the [WKExtensionDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKExtensionDelegate_protocol/).